# Models as Scala case classes interacting with DAO?

Tags: scala, models, slick

I was starting a design involving Scala case classes as models, and I was wondering about a design decision.

Let's imagine we have two models, a `User` model and an `Order` model. The `Order` model references the `User` model as a foreign key.

```
case class User(id: UserId, [Other fields...], password: String)
case class Order(id: OrderId, [Other fields...], userId: UserId)
```

Then, given this design, we would have an `Orders` DAO with a method `findByUser` method.

My question is: would it be good design to have an `orders` method in `User` that calls this DAO method, and thus making the system more OO, or is it better to keep layers isolated and not include this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you understand you correctly, you're asking about the Active Record Pattern. As any pattern, it has its pros and cons, you can find more about it online. Here are some of them:

http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-1-active-record

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70291/what-are-the-drawbacks-to-the-activerecord-pattern

[Active Record Design Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174129/active-record-design-pattern)

In a Play2 project, I firstly used the pattern, mainly because of Ebean support. However, since I needed a bit more logic for persisting some models, extension of it turned cumbersome. In the end, I separated everything: separate service, separate model, separate DAO. That also helped me easily switch between repository layer implementations (in the end I could experiment with Spring Data JPA, Hibernate etc. more freely)

Comment: Hi Haris, thanks for your answer. Yes, I think my question may be related to Active Record Design Pattern (I'm still going through your links). Do you have any reference about ways of separating different model-related layers on a Play2 project? Thanks

Comment: I don't have any online resources about that at my hand, I can search a bit for it, but in short, what I had on the project is:

1) a model, e.g. Order
2) a repository/DAO interface, e.g. OrderDAO
3) a service, which is called by the controller, e.g. OrderService, which has an instance of OrderDAO, and performs any additional logic needed (e.g. converting the price from $ to € using some API). The OrderDAO is autowired. It proved very extensible for me.

Comment: Thanks Haris. I guess that's close to the cake pattern, I'll take a look on that.